# How to enable Flash debugger?

Tags: flash, debugging

Haven't been able to find the solution to this anywhere.

I installed the Flash debugger projector from http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html but the debugger still does not run when I debug a SWF (with debugging enabled) in Flash Pro CS5.

Anyone have an idea of what's going on?

Thanks for any help.

Chris

Comment: When yo say you debug a SWF in Flash Pro CS5, do you mean you have the ActionScript source code for the project, and select the Debug command in Flash CS5, or do you only have the SWF, no source code, as Soulseekah is talking about in his answer?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer. I'm trying to get the debugger projector to run my SF from Flash Pro CS5, as it has some extra options.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think you can debug SWF, since they do not contain ActionScript code. You can, however get traces from the SWF into a file if you enable `TraceOutputFileEnable=1` in the .cfg file. More information that may help here: http://www.actionscript.org/resources/articles/207/1/Trace-and-debug-ActionScript-from-your-browser/Page1.html and here http://fatlinesofcode.philipandrews.org/2009/03/28/actionscript-debugging-within-the-browser/

Also check out this FireFox plugin: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flashtracer/

Another option is to `Begin Remote Debug Session` in Flash IDE. The traces will appear in the Output window of the IDE, when the SWF is open in the browser.

If you have access to the code, you can try De MonsterDebugger (it will require implementation of its classes inside the SWF though) http://demonsterdebugger.com/

Comment: Thank you, though I have all that setup =) My problem is that the Flash debug projector won't run. It worked before but for some reason it doesn't anymore =\

Comment: Are you Flash Debug Projector classes inside the SWF? Because if they're not you won't be able to see them, same with traces, if there are no traces in the code nothing will ever show. SWFs are compiled. You could try to decompile and sift through the assembly, but I don't think that's effective.

Comment: Oh no, my only problem is getting the debug projector to run. Everything else works fine. =)

Comment: No errors. It appears to be a setup issue, so another machine won't help. Thanks though!